# Loop does not recognize string of char in C

Tags: c, loops, char

I am writing a code and I need to use a loop. I am reading data from a file (data.txt) that looks like this:

```
IMPORT 450

EXPORT 200

IMPORT 100
```

and so on.

Here is the segment of the code that I am having trouble with

```
inputfile = fopen("c:\\class\\data.txt","r");
fscanf(inputfile,"%s %f", &transaction, &amount);

do{                 
     total += amount;             
     printf("Data %s  %f   %f\n", transaction, amount, total);
     fscanf(inputfile, "%s", &transaction);

}while (transaction == "IMPORT" || transaction == "EXPORT");
```

When I add a printf line to check what 'transaction' is it shows IMPORT, so I am not sure why the do-while loop is not repeating.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `transaction` is a `char` array, the comparison

```
transaction == "IMPORT"
```

will compare the address of `transaction` against the address of the string literal `"IMPORT"`.

You need to use

```
while (strcmp(transaction, "IMPORT") == 0 ||
       strcmp(transaction, "EXPORT") == 0)
```

to compare strings in C.

Answer (score 1):

What type is `transaction`?

In order to use it with `fscanf`'s `%s` operator it probably is `char[]`, and in that case you need to use `strcmp`; the `==` operator will compare character pointer addresses, rather than contents.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to check transaction == "IMPORT" C only compares the pointer of the first char. That doenst work really well. Maybe try this code:

```
int str_equal(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int i, len;

    if ((len = strlen(str1)) != strlen(str2))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (toupper(str1[i]) != toupper(str2[i]))
    {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably like this

```
    while(2==fscanf(inputfile,"%s %f", transaction, &amount)){
        if(strcmp("IMPORT", transaction)==0)
            total += amount;
        else if(strcmp("EXPORT", transaction)==0)
            total -= amount;
        else
            break;
        printf("Data %s  %f   %f\n", transaction, amount, total);
    }
```